# Virtual box stuck on post install scripts

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, redhat, packer

Virtual box stuck on post install scripts while installing some custome redhat box. Is there any way to see the log or something to find out what script is hanging and why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux has a number of virtual consoles that you can access with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>. Each function key (F1...F10) is a different virtual console. They behave like virtual desktops/virtual terminals.  During the install process the screen you are seeing is one of the virtual consoles. In another virtual console (Maybe <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>?) you will see the logs from the installer, Anaconda.  You should also be able to get one terminal with a shell where you could run commands to investigate.

Here's a note from the RHEL 6 Install Guide. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/installation_guide/sn-guimode-virtual-consoles-x86

Comment: Also, I have already found it, that was what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the VirtualBox application UI you should be able to double-click on the VM in the left column and see a terminal window. Is this what you need?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the terminal show the screen I have attached above. But, how can I know what are actually that post install scripts are and what they are doing?